# How to extract the exterior point of some coordinate points in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, geometry, coordinates

I have some points in a grid (`x` and `y` coordinates) and want to extract exterior points. I shown this exteriors in a red band in my fig. Points are sorted first based on `x` and then `y`. I check regard points with the same `x` value as subgroups and I export the first and last point of each subgroup. This is my array:

```
import numpy as np
points=np.array([[0.,0.],[1.,0.],[1.,5.],[1.,10.],[2.,0.],[2.,5.],[2.,10.],[2.,15.],\
                [3.,0.],[3.,5.],[3.,10.],[3.,15.],[4.,10.],[4.,15.]])
```

There are five unique x values: `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` which can make subgroups in my points.
I start to pick the first and last point of each subgroup. Than, I sort `points` firstly based on `y` and then `x` using:

```
points= points[np.lexsort((points[:,0],points[:,1]))]
```

to have `points` as:

```
np.array([[0.,0.],[1.,0.],[2.,0.],[3.,0.],[1.,5.],[2.,5.],[3.,5.],[1.,10.],\
          [2.,10.],[3.,10.],[4.,10.],[2.,15.],[3.,15.],[4.,15.]])
```

Then, unique y values are `0`, `5` and `10` and make subgroups and I again take the first and last point of each subgroup. Finally, I want to merge all extracted points and remove the duplicates to have:

```
exteriors=np.array([[0.,0.],[1.,0.],[1.,5.],[1.,10.],[2.,0.],[2.,15.],\
                    [3.,0.],[3.,5.],[3.,15.], [4.,10.], [4.,15.]])
```

I do appreciate any help to do what I want in python.
[image]

Comment: You might want to clarify exactly what step you have a problem with.

Comment: Dear @Thierry Lathuille, I know only separated things. For example I know `np.unique(points[:,1],return_counts=True)` gives me unique values but I have no idea how to use it for achieving what I want. I know only isolated syntaxes but how no idea how to solve my issue.

Comment: unless you are applying some special rules, your drawing is incorrect. Point 1-5 and point 3-5 are not exerior

Comment: The end of your question is like "I have this `points` array, then I do that and that (but we don't know what your data looks like at this point), and I finally want to do that. It would probably be easier to understand what you need if you give us the data at the last step you successfully reached.

Comment: Or you could just explain the rule: is "I want the first and last point of each line, plus the first and last point of each column" a good description of it?

Comment: Dear @Jakub Dóka, they are. If you sort points first based on y and then x, these two will be the first and last points of the subgroup with y=5.

Comment: As long as that's the result you want everything is okay, just don't call them exterior please.

Comment: Dear @Thierry Lathuille. First step gives me these points: (0,0), (1,0), (1,10), (2,0), (2,15),(3,0), (3,15), (4,10), (4,15). Second step gives (0,0), (3,0), (1,5), (3,5), (1,10), (4,10), (2,15),(4,15).

Comment: Dear @ Thierry Lathuille, they are exactly like rows and columns. The first and last point of each row and column (without repetition)